# How to both preserve and correct an OP's mistake

Tags: discussion

I made a mistake in my question, and commentators have corrected the mistake. Rather than correct the mistake (thus rendering the comments out-of-date and making an answer look silly), do you think it would be better to strike through (line through) the original mistake or to prefix with a question mark?

> The proscribed medication
>
> The <strike>proscribed</strike> prescribed medication
>
> The ?proscribed medication

And incidentally, is using the HTML strike tag the best way to render a strike through, or is there a built-in one (such as there is for *italic*)?

Answer (score 5):

It's probably best to just fix it silently and flag the comments as *obsolete*. The extra noise from a strikethrough or question mark probably isn't worth it.

As for strikethroughs, the `<s>` tag is the only way. Markdown has no special strikethrough code.

Comment: First, he refers also to an answer ("making an answer look sill"y), not only comments. And secondly, why would you zap the commenters who contributed?

Answer (score 2):

The main issue is with the answers, not the comments. Yes, I recommend you to strike through. This is what I did [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37536/explain-the-verb-tense-in-i-wish-i-never-woke-up-this-morning).
 This way the answers do not necessarily need to be updated (you need to appreciate the  effort spent) and still make sense. You may need to inform with a comment within the answers that you have changed your question.